# Access elements inside a Layout View

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a website which uses MVC model.
I have a Layout page and 4 pages(home,contactus,aboutus,ourwork) which use this Layout. I am having this situation where I want to use the html element defined in layout page in one of the page(ex. home).
use in the sense modify certain property of that element(using javascript).

example:
lets say there is a button defined in layout page and i want to change the display property of the button when some action happens in home page

Comment: Can you share some code or example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! You have to create a global Javascript file and add that into the layout body and select the element you want, e.g.:

If the element id is `readm`, put the script into that file:

```js
var readm= $("#readm");
```

Include the script file src into the layout body, e.g.:
If the filename is `accesselement.js`:

```html
<script src="accesselement.js">
```

Use the variable name in your view in which that element is required.
That's it.